# Установка ширины изображения

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать,чтобы карта не вылазила за пределы экрана и не появлялся скролл бар?

Нужно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня вышло вот так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.attention{
 background-color: #eef1ec;
}

.attention__block{
 padding-top: 162px;
}

.map{
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<section class="attention">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="attention__block">
              <h2 class="attention__title">
                Built with High Attention to Details
              </h2>
              <p class="attention__text">
                Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img src="img/map.png" alt="map" class="map">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` в нужном месте

Comment: @andreymal на скриншоте, как должно быть, картинка не обрезается , она целая

Comment: Тогда непонятно желаемое поведение. Если открыть сайт, к примеру, на телефоне с экраном шириной 320 пикселей — как в эти 320 пикселей должна впихиваться картинка, если не обрезаться и не скроллиться?

Comment: @andreymal ну может можно как-то сделать,чтобы картинка размещалась по ширине блока и не выходила за его пределы ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.attention{
 background-color: #eef1ec;
}

.attention__block{
 padding-top: 162px;
}

.map{
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.map img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="attention">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="attention__block">
              <h2 class="attention__title">
                Built with High Attention to Details
              </h2>
              <p class="attention__text">
                Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 map">
            <img src="http://eastwestindependent.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/world-map-png-35417.png" alt="map" class="map">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Получается не то,что нужно. Надо,чтобы картинка прикасалась к краю экрана , это можно увидеть на скриншоте "как должно быть". Мб мне надо сделать container-fluid и как-то поиграться с шириной ?

Comment: омг)))
Это делается с помощью background-image, в фотошопе находите слой с картинкой, смотрим размер к примеру 1920х560 рх, далее создаем новый холст с этими размерами, и вырезаем на него изображение сохраняем в png. и пишем следующее:

.attention {
background: url(img/map.png) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

А div в котором находится картинка <div class="col-lg-6 map"> удаляем
Плюс на мобильных у вас тоже будет фон в виде карты